# CodeModel Interface creation Java

Tags: java

I am currently working on dynamic java source code creation and I ran into a problem. Everything is working fine so far but not with interfaces.

```
UMLClass = codemodel._class(JMod.PUBLIC, umlInterface.getName(), ClassType.INTERFACE);
```

//UMLClass is a JDefinedClass, umlInterface.getName() is just a String

If I try running this code, it creates source code looking like this:

```
public class Bull {

    private final static long bli;
    private final static double bla;

    abstract void abstractOperation();
}
```

It doesn't name it interface and I have not figured out, why, because the JType was set to INTERFACE which should create an interface?

Comment: PS: Same goes for enumerations. For example I get:

Comment: public class Weekdays {

    MONDAY,
    TUESDAY,
    WENDESDAY,
    THURSDAY,
    FRIDAY,
    SATURDAY,
    SUNDAY;

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in CodeModel:

> JCodeModel._class(fullyqualifiedName, ClassType.INTERFACE) create a
> concrete class if fullyqualifiedName is in root package. When calling
> jCodeModel._class(fullyqualifiedName, ClassType.INTERFACE),if
> fullyqualifiedName does not have a ".", the classtype is set to CLASS.

https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-codemodel/issues/24

So you need to specify the fully qualified name for your interface.

The following does the job:

```
    JCodeModel codeModel = new JCodeModel();
    JDefinedClass bull = codeModel._class(JMod.PUBLIC, "com.Bull", ClassType.INTERFACE);
    System.out.println("is interface " + bull.isInterface());
    codeModel.build(new File("/home/user"));
    System.out.println("done!");
    
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/user/com/Bull.java"));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
    }
```